# Field validation in WTF Forms Flask, redirect method

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I am trying to create my first Flask web application and found the following problem, I have two pages, the first page should take players names and give the names to the next page, but unfortunately name validation does not work due to some reason, I can  keep the required fields empty and go to next page with empty names fields.

Flask code:

```
class ChooseName(FlaskForm):
    first_player_name = StringField("Choose first player name: ", [DataRequired()])
    second_player_name = StringField("Choose second player name: ", [DataRequired()])
    button = SubmitField("Confirm")


@app.route('/')
def index():
    form = ChooseName()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        return redirect(url_for('mega'))
    return render_template('TIC_TAC_TOE_index.html', form=form) 


@app.route('/game_page', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def mega():
    player1 = request.args.get('first_player_name')
    player2 = request.args.get('second_player_name')
    ......
    return render_template('mega.html', form=form, error=error, x=x, 
    turn=turn,tornado=tornado, renew=renew, player1=player1,player2=player2)
```

HTML template:

```
<form action="{{url_for('mega')}}" method="get">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    <h4>Please choose players names!</h4>
    {{form.first_player_name.label}}  {{form.first_player_name}} <br> <br>
    {{form.second_player_name.label}}  {{form.second_player_name}} <br> <br>
    {{form.button}} <br> <br>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well looking at your function **Mega()**, you're not returning anything on the next page. You're just accepting the input but aren't returning it in any form.

```
from wtforms import Form, StringField, validators, SubmitField
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from flask import Flask, render_template, request


class ChooseName(FlaskForm):
    first_player_name = StringField("Choose first player name: ", [validators.DataRequired()])
    second_player_name = StringField("Choose second player name: ", [validators.DataRequired()])
    button = SubmitField("Confirm")

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "IT_IS_SECRET"

@app.route('/')
def index():
    form = ChooseName()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        return redirect(url_for('mega'))
    return render_template('TIC_TAC_TOE_index.html', form=form)

@app.route('/game_page', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def mega():
    player1 = request.args.get('first_player_name')
    player2 = request.args.get('second_player_name')
    return player1 + ' ' + player2


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5000,debug=True)
```

Try to run this code, I hope this helps. :-)

Comment: Unfortunately it did not help, I still can keep the fields empty and go to the next page and as a result I got an empty page. Genereated url was http://127.0.0.1:5000/game_page?csrf_token=ImExYmViNjNhZTIwYmIxZjBmOWM3MTNlYjMyMjI3MTk0NTQ2MzM5NjEi.D2kLQw.mJR9SE0BW9TJWPOTq_49aj_jSY0&first_player_name=&second_player_name=&button=Confirm

Comment: Copy my complete code as it is and paste it in a new file and run this code. It is perfectly working at my end and let me know if it works at yours too!

Comment: I've done it, but undortunately I still get empty page (page without names) if I do not put any text into textboxes. If I put information in textboxes I get what is expected, otherwise just empty fields. Validation does not work - no idea why =(

Comment: I now did the task using standard html <input>, but still have no idea why wtf forms does not do text field check in my program, let me know if you get any idea. Thanks for help.

Comment: Can you post your complete code? Like including the imports? Because when I try to submit the form without data using my code, there's a pop up which states "please fill out this field" which means the validators are working just fine.

Comment: https://repl.it/@ghorpadeyash/FlaskTicTacToe
Try this out.
Run it, copy the url in your tab and try to submit. Is the Validator Working?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189877/discussion-between-artiom-kozyrev-and-yash-ghorpade).

Comment: Thank you very much! It works fine now, but what did you change?

Comment: You're welcome. I guess there must be a problem in your imports and validators. I've basically made a few changes in your ChooseName function and validators too! Well, if that worked, could you mark the answer as accepted?

Answer (score 1):

This is because your action is pointing to the *mega* view, so the code from *index* `if form.validate_on_submit():` is not being executed.

You should change the action attribute and method in your form. The code should be as follows:

HTML template:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    <h4>Please choose players names!</h4>
    {{form.first_player_name.label}}  {{form.first_player_name}} <br> <br>
    {{form.second_player_name.label}}  {{form.second_player_name}} <br> <br>
    {{form.button}} <br> <br>
</form>
```

Views:

```
from flask import session

@app.route('/')
def index():
    form = ChooseName()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        session['first_player_name'] = form.first_player_name.data
        session['second_player_name'] = form.second_player_name.data
        return redirect(url_for('mega'))
    return render_template('TIC_TAC_TOE_index.html', form=form) 


@app.route('/game_page', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def mega():
    player1 = session.pop('first_player_name')
    player2 = session.pop('second_player_name')
    ......
    return render_template('mega.html', form=form, error=error, x=x, 
    turn=turn,tornado=tornado, renew=renew, player1=player1,player2=player2)
```

You can learn more about WTForms here https://j2logo.com/tutorial-flask-leccion-3-formularios-wtforms/